# Modeling of Big Bang

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, big-bang

Well, I’m just an ordinary High School passed student. I had passion towards space-time- relativity and other things related with physics :D
I have been watching theories of physics like Big Bang from childhood and I have a question

[image: Big Bang]

this is the most popular image of Big Bang. Since beginning is a point why everything started in one way? Why not this might be possible?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkANt.jpg
Hmm.. Look since it’s a point its possible for events occurred in all possible directions ( infinite ). All these will make a Sphere of spate events around the point of big bang. And yes maybe it’s what a universe with infinite copies of itself.  Since those are separate from each other one’s presence will not affect one another other, but each of them will grow equally and laws of physics are valid for all those copies

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Just to note, in that first image, to the right means forward in time. The expansion of space is actually "spherical" (i.e. the same in all directions) though the universe is not observably finite and, as answers to the question @JohnRennie linked above explain, the big bang happened everywhere, not at a point. So 'spherical' is misleading.